# AWS Training - No Eligible Exams Shown?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am attempting to schedule an AWS Exam (Certified Solutions Architect - Associate), but nothing is showing up under the eligible exams section.

I am in the United States and PearsonVUE is unable to assist.

[image]

In my profile settings, I have experience with AWS set to 3-5 years and the only eligibility requirements I have found for booking the exams are:

> (1) At least 1 year of working experience in designing and deploying
> applications on the AWS platform. (2) Expertise in at least 1 high-level
> programming language,  ability to identify the requirements of an
> application, defining best practices for securing the AWS application
> and deploying hybrid systems with AWS components is required.

What am I missing? Has anybody run into a similar issue? where were you able to receive support?

Comment: Good place and community for aws cert questions and info is here https://old.reddit.com/r/AWSCertifications/ . Worth checking/asking there.

Comment: I logged into the AWS certification site, clicked **Schedule an Exam** and it came with lots of them! The page was https://www.certmetrics.com/amazon/candidate/exam_scheduling.aspx (but I logged-in via AWS).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming